# How to modified the title/leftButton/rightButton on the navigation bar of a NavigatorIOS after the scene is shown?

Tags: react-native

One direction is to call the setState of the NavigatorIOS and so to make it rerender with new title/leftButton/right. However, in the context of the scene, it's not naturally ok to touch the NavigatorIOS, since in the props there is no ref to it.

Another direction is to try some method such as put/replace/... on the props.navigator, to change the navigation stack. The replace method seems to be a right choice, but nothing happened when I call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [NavigatorIOSExample](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/NavigatorIOSExample.js) of React Native.

> The component is replaced, but there is currently no way to change the right button or title of the current route.

Comment: I've look into the native code, and found that it is because in the master code there is nothing to update the navigation bar when the stack is changed.
And here's an effort to fix it:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/2526